# Prove that if $A \subseteq 5$ and $B \subseteq C, A \subseteq C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem with a proof.

Assume that $A,B,C \subseteq U $
Prove that if $A \subseteq 5$ and $B \subseteq C, A \subseteq C$

My first question is if it is possible for $A$ to be a subset of a number. If it is, how does that relate to $C$? Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible for $A$ to be a subset of a number. The notation $A \subseteq 5$ makes no sense.

Comment: @user133281 Of course it is, it's the best way to make sense of things, actually.

Comment: Then what does the notation $A \subseteq 5$ mean...?

Comment: @user133281 To me it means that $A$ is a proper subset of $5$. **Edit:** I should point out that $5:=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a set?

Comment: @user133281 Read the first paragraph of the section [The contemporary standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#The_contemporary_standard) in this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to prove that if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ then it follows that $A\subseteq C$, *i.e.* the subset relation is transitive. Otherwise the claim is wrong.

Comment: @GitGud: thanks for the link. Not sure that that's what going on here though.

Comment: @user133281 Me neither, that's why I'm not answering the question. I don't understand the context.

Comment: My guess is that $5$ is a misprint/typo and should be $B$. Then we have the true $$A\subseteq B \land B\subseteq C \implies A\subseteq C$$

Answer (score 1):

As stated the problem is false - those criterion are too weak. Let $U$ be the union of $5$ and $C$, where $5\not\in C$. Then let $A$ be any subset of $5$ and let $B$ be any subset of $C$ and you have a counter example.

It is possible that instead you wish to prove that if $A\subset B$ and $B\subset C$, then $A\subset C$. I will provide that proof as well.

Definition of subset: $(A\subset C)\iff((\forall a\in A)(a\in C))$.

Let $a$ be some element of $A$. Then since $A\subset B$, we have that $a\in B$ by definition. However, $B\subset C$ as well, so $a$, by virtue of being in $B$, must be in $C$. Thus every element of $A$ is in $C$ and so $A\subset C$.